# Angular 9 Locale data for 'en-US' cannot be found. No locale data will be included for this locale

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9, angular-i18n

I am getting this strange warning

`Locale data for 'en-US' cannot be found.  No locale data will be included for this locale`
 when running `ng build --configuration=prod --localize`

here is my angular.json

```
// omitted
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en-US",
    "locales": {
      "sr-Latn": {
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.sr.xlf",
        "baseHref": "/sr/"
      }
    }
  },
// omitted
```

The documentation clearly states en-US is imported by default. 
To make things worse, when i change sourceLocale to any other language (say 'de'), warning message goes away.
Manually registering en-US locale data doesnt help either

Comment: It is the same for hr-HR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working if you set sourceLocale to `en`.

- But i cant figure out why the default value `en-US` dosnt work.

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en",
    "locales": {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the most recent version 9.0.2 you can specify the sourceLocale baseHref

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": {
      "baseHref": "/",
      "code": "en"
    },
    "locales": {
      "fr": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
      "de": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf",
      "es": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
      "it": "src/locale/messages.it.xlf",
      "ja": "src/locale/messages.ja.xlf",
      "ko": "src/locale/messages.ko.xlf",
      "zh": {
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.cn.xlf",
        "baseHref": "/cn/"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is annoying indeed. The compiler expects to have en-US resource and even compiles the application using en-US and base-href.

This is how I solved this.

1) I just ignore the warning and en-US output directory.

2) I compile the application twice. First without --localized option. This compiles the original application, uses \ as base-href and does not used any translation files. Then I compile another time with --localized and that compiles all my languages with base-href matching the language codes.

```
ng build --prod --outputPath=dist/original
ng build --prod --outputPath=dist/localized --localize
```

3) I deploy the original build from `dist/original` and all the other builds from `dist/localized` except the en-US directory.

Comment: My problem is different. I actually do want to keep en-US build. Problem is missing locale data for en-US even though en-US data should be installed by default

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Like you said, the default for `LOCALE_ID` seems to be `en-US`, as this is what it represents when nothing is specified.

Further, looking at `@angular/common/locales/*` it seems like, the default for registerLocaleData is `en`. `@angular/common/locales/en` exists, `@angular/common/locales/en-US` does not exist!
Same with `de-DE`: `@angular/common/locales/de-DE` does not exist, but `@angular/common/locales/de` does.

For now, I have switched everything to `en`/`de` and it works:

---

Example localising for English and German:

**angular.json**

```
[...]
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "de": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf"
        }
      }
[...]
```

**app.module.ts**

```
[...]
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, localeEn);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with that fact that the file is named en-US-POSIX as seen here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/locales/en-US-POSIX.ts

Trying to dynamically `import('@angular/common/locales/en-US-POSIX')` works.

So trying this might work

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en-US-POSIX",
    "locales": {...}
}
```